# MySQL: ORDER BY clause slows down MATCH AGAINST search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, match-against

I have the following MySQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(share_id) FROM pd_shares WHERE section = 'news' AND item_id = news.article_id) AS count_shares, article_id, link, title, publish_date, description, source FROM pd_news AS news WHERE (MATCH (title_ascii, description_ascii) AGAINST ('".match_against($_GET["sn"])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND article_id > " . $last_index . " ORDER BY article_id ASC LIMIT 0,$limit";
```

When I do a search, the query loads 513.24 ms with the ORDER BY clause.  When I remove it, it runs 77.12 ms.

Both `title_ascii` and `description_ascii` are FULLTEXT.

How can I rewrite this Query so the run speed loads much faster than it currently is?

EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     news    fulltext    PRIMARY,news_search     news_search     0   NULL    1   Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  pd_shares   ref     section     section     19  const,my_database.news.article_id   2   Using index condition
```

Comment: Can you post your EXPLAIN output?

Comment: Your EXPLAIN output told us that query should be pretty fast because it only handle few rows. Do you call EXPLAIN on actual dataset?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know the schema for the referenced tables (pd_shares and pd_news).  I moved the sub-select to a normal join and added a group by clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT
          article_id
        , link
        , title
        , publish_date
        , description
        , source 
        , COUNT(shares.share_id) AS count_shares
        FROM pd_news AS news 
        LEFT JOIN pd_shares shares
            ON shares.section = 'news' AND shares.item_id = news.article_id
        WHERE (MATCH (title_ascii, description_ascii) AGAINST ('".match_against($_GET["sn"])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
            AND article_id > " . $last_index . " 
        GROUP BY article_id
        ORDER BY article_id ASC LIMIT 0, $limit";
```